# Oracle: Conditional Grouping

Tags: oracle

I am having the data in following format :

```
 cons_Type   COLUMN_NAME
    P        (COL1)
    R        (COL6_REFERENCE)
    R        (COL6_REFERENCE)
    U        (COL5_COM_UNIQUE)
    U        (COL3_UNIQUE,COL4_COM_UNIQUE)
```

Finally, I want to listAgg column_name, cons_type wise where cons_type will be 
either 'P' or 'U' only.

Other cons_type like 'R' must not be list aggregated using LISTAGG() function.

and final expected output must be in following format.

```
cons_Type   COLUMN_NAME
P            (COL1)
R            (COL6_REFERENCE)
R            (COL6_REFERENCE)
U            (COL3_UNIQUE,COL4_COM_UNIQUE),(COL5_COM_UNIQUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select 
    "cons_Type", 
    "COLUMN_NAME"
from tbl
where "cons_Type" not in ('P', 'U')

union all

select 
    "cons_Type", 
    LISTAGG("COLUMN_NAME" , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "cons_Type")
from tbl
where "cons_Type" in ('P', 'U')
group by "cons_Type"

order by "cons_Type"
```

**Demo** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c276e/15)